# How to get value from custom attribute in angular 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular5

I'm new to angular. I have added custom attribute to span tag like below

```
<span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="padding: 2px;cursor: pointer;background: #e60000;color: #fff" (click)="loadnewsdetail()" [attr.newsid]="news.NewsId">Read More </span>
```

I want to get value of attribute newsid for that I'm doing below code using jQuery

```
 loadnewsdetail() {
         var a = $(this).attr('newsid');
         alert(a);
}
```

It giving me undefined. How to do this in angular and why it's undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of getting the newsId you can just pass it as parameter on `click`

```
(click)="loadnewsdetail(news.NewsId)"
```

and get it like this.

```
 loadnewsdetail(newsId) {

    alert(newsId);
  }
```

or if you want to get the attribute you can pass an event to the function (actually not needed in your case). but, here is how you can do it.

```
(click)="loadnewsdetail($event)"
```

and get that value using

```
loadnewsdetail(newsId) { 
    alert(newsId.target.getAttribute("newsid"));
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vizz7r)